# Illustrator - warp according shape without resizing font size

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a label to do and it's curved. How can I put text/images on it in a way to follow the blue shape?

[image: This is the label]

Thanks

Comment: Create your label and then arc everything.

Comment: And how can I arc everything according to the shape? I don't wanna do this just using my eye.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your artwork and place it **below** that shape in the stacking order. Then use `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object` to get the art to distort to that particular shape.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a situation where the art for your label always has a static outside shape (even if it is an invisible rectangle), you can try and use the Warp > Arc (or Arch) effect on the group which contains the art. The benefit of doing this by eye the first time would be a template which can be used in the future (by replacing elements within the group), and also the Effects have advantage of persistence and portability when saved as graphic styles (When the distortion needs to be applied to new art for any reason).

The technique begins with using some trial and error to warp a straight rectangle via the Arc or Arch effect until it matches your curved template. When a "good enough" setting of degrees is achieved, theoretically the warp should make any art whose outside boundaries are same dimension as the rectangle, warp at a "good enough" level. However, there may be additional difficulties, for all kinds of distortion, probably, when art has complex appearances or areas with clipping paths and masks...
[image: screenshot 1: testing phase]

[image: Screenshot 2: match found!]

[image: Screenshot 3: Live text and vector art warped!]

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer works but if you want the type with a space around it you could use `Object > Path > Offset path`. Use a negative value to get a smaller shape inside then either apply the envelope distort or use the `Type on a path` tool (under Type tool). Both shown in image...

[image]